# Prevent auto retrieval of e-mail when opening Mail in iPhone: is it possible?

Tags: iphone, email

Whenever I open the standard iPhone mail client, my mail is automatically retrieved regardless of the "manual" setting in my email settings. Since I have multiple e-mail accounts configured, this can be a very timely process and with the lack of a read all function, this is really a pain.

**Is there a way to prevent this?**

Answer (score 2):

Put it in airplane mode before opening email app.

Comment: Good suggestion. Not sure if the OP would like it though.

Answer (score 1):

I notice sometimes it will not check automatically if I make sure I am at the mail accounts start page when I exit the mail application. This is with push off and manual check. When I am in an specific account and I close mail and come back, it always checks accounts. This isn't a solid answer, but this is the only way I have seen it behave like you desire. It only does it sometimes though and might have to do with me checking the mail recently. I do check my mail often. Good question to bring up.